# Reviving rubber tree - almost all leaves are gone - one shoot left

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, plant-health, growth, ficus

I moved away for a year, and left my rubber tree with a friend - unfortunately I think the move shocked it, and it's now lost almost all of its leaves.

Do you have any tips on what I could do to revive it? Should I repot it?

Thanks!

[image: My rubber tree]

Answer (score 2):

Water it, more light and cut it back to within a few inches of the soul.  Patience will reward you with new sprouts as these plants bud readily from old wood

Answer (score 1):

I'd also recommend more light, but instead of cutting I'd recommend adding fertilizer sticks to the soil, about 3-4 of them. Thus they ensure a steady release of nutrients for a prolonged period of time. Cutting is not really necessary as once the plant starts growing it will sport new buds even on the barren stem where the leaves used to be. Just ensure it gets enough light.